# How to center KDE application launcher from latte dock?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, launcher, customization, latte-dock

The application launcher position doesn't match center screen. I use latte dock. Is there any way to center the launcher position?

[image: screenshot of dock]

Comment: It seems to be perfectly centered on the dock icon... I don't think this is configurable in latte dock. You should put in a feature request. However, I'm fairly certain that the main contributor has stepped away from the project.

Comment: is there any alternatives to latte dock ?